# How to solve this IMO competition problem?

Tags: contest-math

Let $n>2$ be an integer. Let $f$ be a real-value function on a plane such that for every regular n-gon with vertices $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$, $f(A_1)+f(A_2)+...+f(A_n)=0$. Prove that $f$ is zero function.

Putnam 2009 asked to prove this for the case of a square which is much easier for me. However I don't have a clue on how to prove the general case.

Comment: The AOPS forums usually have good solutions.

Comment: Could you show your solution for the case of a square?

Comment: BTW this is a 1996 Romanian team selection IMO question.

Comment: @Supermario: You can find a solution here: http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2009s.pdf (first question)

Comment: @Supermario: Let $\langle x,y\rangle$ be any point in the plane. Consider the nine points $\langle x+i,y+j\rangle$ with $i,j\in\{-1,0,1\}$. Add the values of $A$ at the four corner points, twice the values of $A$ at the four side points, and four times the value at the centre point. The total is $0$, since it's the sum of the totals for the four unit squares. The total for the corner points is $0$, and so is the total for the side points, which also form a square. Thus, the value at the centre must also be $0$.

Comment: There is a solution here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h51933p327816

Comment: @Dair: Thank you